# Is SharePoint 2013 compatible with Crowdstrike?

Tags: sharepoint-server, anti-virus

We're replacing our Sophos AV software with Crowdstrike across the IT estate - including our SharePoint Server 2013 Farm. However, I'm acutely aware that most AV software is incompatible with SharePoint servers due to the significant performance issues that arise - a huge risk when there are >14k users. Does anyone have any experience with deploying Crowdstrike to a SharePoint Server Farm? Were there compatibility issues? If so, how did you over come them? Any lessons learned? Crowdstrike have provided standard, generic assurances but nothing convincing especially when the mode is changed from "Detect" to "Protect"...

Apologies if this isn't the appropriate forum to raise this - the Stack Overflow Community were unable to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always follow the exclusion rules. Microsoft will not provide a support statement for 3rd party solutions, such as anti-virus.

Keep in mind unless the AV you're using is SharePoint-integrated, it will not scan files uploaded/downloaded to/from SharePoint.

[Certain folders may have to be excluded from antivirus scanning when you use file-level antivirus software in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-you-use-file-level-antivirus-software-in-sharepoint-01cbc532-a24e-4bba-8d67-0b1ed733a3d9)